# .net TAG entering control

Tags: .net, user-controls, .net-2.0, tagging

I would like to have tag entering functionality in .net forms app.  Framework is 2.0.

I am looking for a text entry control that would behave like the one below this field (anyone who ever entered a question will know), so:

- autocomplete
- drop down popup

are a must.

However, I need it to display an icon beside the tag, which will describe its type:

- person
- place
- product
- company
- and so on...

EDIT:

Yeah, it should include multiple tags, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Telerik's Winforms Combobox](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/dropdown-and-list.aspx#autocomplete-modes) almost matches your requirements. It would not allow multiple tags to be entered in one textbox but does give you a rich UI for listing tags including images. You could simply copy the rest of SO's tagging UI e.g. once they hit enter, add it to a list element below the combobox.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll probably use devx controls for that (since I'm into them)